# animate a UIView while moving it in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation

i need to animate a UIView while it is moving from one place to another, i am using the following:

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        _whileSpitImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"picture.png"];
         _whileSpitImageView.frame = CGRectMake(160, 300, 50, 50);
    } completion:nil];

}
```

but the view is just moving and not animating while moving, any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "not animating"?

Comment: Is it full of your `didSelectItemAtIndexPath ` method? Where did you create `_whileSpitImageView` and you create it by using autolayout or set frame?

Comment: it is just an image in the UIView moving, i need it to animate while moving, maybe set a series of images and animate it while it moves?

Comment: Again, what do you mean by "animate it"? Do you mean changing the `imageView`'s images?

Comment: the image needs to move across the canvas and it needs to change color for example while it is moving...

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing UIView animateWithDuration. The issue is that animateWithDuration only is able to animate some properties of a UIView, these are the frame, bounds, center, transform, alpha, backgroundColor and contentStretch ([Animations From Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html)).

You might want to do a step by step animation. For example:

```
var imageView: UIImageView?
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
    imageView?.alpha = 0.0},
    completion: {(_ finished: Bool) -> Void in
    imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "newImage")
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        imageView?.alpha = 1.0
    })
})
```

Note. I'm not sure if the syntax is fully correct, I used an online converter. But the logic is there. The original Objective-C pre-translation is as follows

```
UIImageView *imageView;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    imageView.alpha = 0.0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"newImage"]];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        imageView.alpha = 1.0;
    }];
}];
```